# How to refresh numbering after delete row Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help in Excel VBA. I made a worksheet, where I can add some informations in specific row. After adding, every row has a numbering. For example:

```
A - No   B - Name   C - Surname
1         John           Kon  
2         Elizabeth      Now
3         Patrick        Yesterday
```

I made also User Form, which makes possible to delete specific row. This means that if I want to delete the second item, I select that it should be deleted. Unfortunately, after deleting the second item, the numbering does not work properly. In this case, the numbers 1 and 3 remain. What should the code look like that refreshes the numbering to the last filled cell so that the order is still preserved?

I would appreciate your help.

I tried something like that, but it doesn't work properly. It delete row properly, but refreshing numbering still doesn't work.

```
If usunwpis = vbYes Then
    Selection.Delete
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("F24:F" & LastRow) = Evaluate("IF(ROW(F24:F" & LastRow - 2 & "),ROW(F24:F" & LastRow - 2 & "))")
    MsgBox "Deleted rows"
    Unload Me
```

Comment: What is the idea (the business case) of numbers that changes? And if it is usefull: Have you thought about simply using `=Row()+1` as a formula?

Comment: I tried this solution, but if I use this a formula, then when someone removes a given range, the rest of the part will generate #ARG

Comment: Have you tried `=ROW()` without parameter? That should work always, no matter what you delete or move.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is still not quite a working solution. UserForm prompts the user for a specific number as a numbering, and removes the row based on that. The UserForm does not find this value when the formula is used.
Perhaps there is a solution to get around this?

Comment: Why it shouldn't find the number when using a formula? Plus, as number and row number are always in sync, you even don't have to search for the number, you can directly compute the row from it

Comment: It is good idea, but still there is a problem. If someone adds a person, then the numbering appears next to that person. I have to use the formula if for this. Everything works until someone deletes the item. Then #ARG appears.

Answer (score 0):

I managed with a simple for loop

```
Dim g As Integer
        
  For g = 24 To Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row
      Cells(g, 15) = g - 23
  Next g
```

24 is my starting row, O is a column, and 15 is the column number.